# about closed set

Tags: general-topology

In this lectures [Nets](https://www.mathematik.hu-berlin.de/%7Ewendl/Sommer2017/Topologie1/nets.pdf) at page 4 in the proof of theorem 3.1 they have

> Conversely, suppose that $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is not continuous, so there exists an open set $\mathcal{U} \subset Y$ for which $f^{-1}(\mathcal{U})$ is not open. The latter means $f^{-1}(\mathcal{U})$ contains a point $x$ for which every neighborhood $\mathcal{V} \subset X$ of $x$ contains a point $x_{\mathcal{V}} \notin f^{-1}(\mathcal{U})$.

why if $f^{-1}(\mathcal{U})$ is not open means $f^{-1}(\mathcal{U})$ contains a point $x$ for which every neighborhood $\mathcal{V} \subset X$ of $x$ contains a point $x_{\mathcal{V}} \notin f^{-1}(\mathcal{U})$.

Comment: A set is open if and only if all its points are interior points. Hence, a set is not open if and only if it has at least a point which is not an interior point.

Comment: @Sassatelli Giulio can you expand the comment as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Let ($X$, $d$) be a metric space. A set $A \subset X$ is called *open* if for every point $x \in A$, there exists an open neighbourhood for which $O_\varepsilon(x) \subset A$, where the open neighbourhood is defined as $O_\varepsilon(x) = \{y \in X: d(x, y) < \varepsilon\}$. Therefore, a set $A$ is called *not open* if there exists an $x \in A$ such that for all open neighbourhoods $O_\varepsilon(x)$ around $x$, $O_\varepsilon(x) \not \subset A$, which is equivalent to $O_\varepsilon(x) \backslash A \neq \emptyset$ for all $O_\varepsilon(x)$, which is in turn equivalent to saying that for all $O_\varepsilon(x)$ there exists a $y \in O_\varepsilon(x)$ such that $y \not \in A$.

Now just replace $A$ by $f^{-1}(\mathcal{U})$ in the above.